# How do I "shift+right click" a taskbar icon when on a touchscreen in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

To access useful actions on taskbar icons like "Open file location", one needs to hold shift when right-clicking, either on the icon directly or on the program name after right-clicking once.

Can I access the same menu from a touchscreen device without a mouse?

Comment: I do not have to shift right click in WIN 10 or 11. What are you missing?

Comment: @John the menu you see when holding shift on a taskbar item can only be reached otherwise if you hover the taskbar item and then right-click the preview that pops up. Both actions are not possible with just gesture control.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do the Shift on a virtual keyboard if you don't have
a physical one, using the
[On-Screen Keyboard](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-the-on-screen-keyboard-osk-to-type-ecbb5e08-5b4e-d8c8-f794-81dbf896267a#ID0EBBD=Windows_10).

Using the On-Screen Keyboard, you click the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key
once to press and hold, then a second click to release the key.